# Creating Tables on the Go using DynamicSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I require to create new tables for every client that signs up for my application.

For Example, I have two tables

```
Order_History_<ClientIdentifier>
Transcation_Log_<ClientIdentifier>
```

In SQL Server, how do I create tables with customized names on the go and how can I query them  according to the client which is accessing my application.

Comment: Why do you need to create separate tables for each client as opposed to having one `Order_History` and one `Transcation_Log` table with a `clientId` column?

Comment: Much like in my answer to your previous question - Needing to do this is very often a sign of poor design.  If you really need separation of data for different customers, use different databases - and make the tables and queries identical.  Of the options available to you, you appear to have settled for the worst one.

Comment: Or if the clients will have different logins you could also use different default schemas for this. With the shared stuff in `dbo` and client specific stuff in a schema for each client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple way:

```
create procedure CreateTableForUser
(
    @UserName nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

declare @createScript nvarchar(max) =
'
create table dbo.Order_History_<ClientIdentifier>
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    val nvarchar(100)
)
'

declare @createScript2 nvarchar(max) =
'
create table dbo.Transcation_Log_<ClientIdentifier>
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    val nvarchar(100)
)
'

set @createScript = REPLACE(@createScript, '<ClientIdentifier>', @UserName)
set @createScript2 = REPLACE(@createScript2, '<ClientIdentifier>', @UserName)

exec sp_executesql @createScript
exec sp_executesql @createScript2

END
```

if you need something more "automatic", like creating the tables from a template table by copying all his fields and keys i would use the sys. views but it's a bit longer to write :P

Comment: Op also wants to query them 'dynamically' too.  I think the op is headed down a blind alley.

Comment: he just needs to create the queries with placeholders and replace when needed; obviously this could lead to BIG security issues though